# Connect two monitors using DVI and/or VGA to USB-C

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, vga-adapter, dvi, vga

I have a new MacBook Pro 15'' and want to connect two older 1080p monitors. Each monitor has a VGA and a DVI port. Is it possible to connect both to a single USB-C port of the MacBook? If so, how do people do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to connect a VGA and a DVI display to one USB-C port on the MacBook, but you need two USB-C adapters in a daisy-chain fashion and a HDMI-DVI adapter.

First you connect the USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter (part number MJ1K2AM) to the MacBook USB-C port, then you connect the USB-C VGA Multiport Adapter (part number MJ1L2AM) to the USB-C port on the Digital AV adapter.

To get the DVI you also need to connect an Apple HDMI to DVI Adapter (part number MJVU2AM) to the HDMI port on the Digital AV adapter which provides you with the DVI port you need.

Now you have a DVI port and a VGA port available and only one USB-C port is used on the MacBook.

The setup (minus the HDMI-DVI adapter which I don't have) would look similar to this:

[image: usbc-hdmi-vga]

Comment: Very nice, didn't expect this to work! In the mean time I found some docking stations online, but they are quite expensive. Not sure which way to go now..

Comment: Another option would be to use a Digital AV adapter which gives you HDMI (and with a converter DVI) and also a full working USB3 port. Attaching a USB3 to VGA (which is actually external USB3 graphics card), such as USB32VGAPRO would give you the additional VGA port, plus it is cheaper than the Apple USB-C to VGA.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend a thunderbolt dock to do this. In my experience it isn't possible to daisy chain the adapters as described in one of the other answers. In fact, the port they are using to daisy chain is only for power in anyway. Yes the connector fits, but doesn’t function.

USB-C docks that offer multiple monitors usually rely on DisplayPort Multi-Stream Transport, which is not supported by macOS. Because of this, these adapters are usually listed as Windows only.

Answer (score 1):

I use a number of older DVI monitors; DVI <-> hdmi adapters (which are passive devices) are readily available for a couple of dollars, as are DVI <-> hdmi cables (for about the same price as a hdmi cable).

hdmi -> VGA adapters are active devices, and more expensive.

Either of these will let you use any of the hdmi adapters for the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can use KVM VGA Switch to Connect one display to multiple PC's / Laptop's

[image: Connect multiple monitors]
<sub>(source: [hdcabling.co.za](https://www.hdcabling.co.za/images/4_Port_USB_KVM_Switch.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Can you please add the link where you found this image?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work... Must you use a HDMI cable?

Apple computer Mac M1 has two type-C Thunderbolt docks and I’m going to just use one of the computers' type-C Thunderbolt dock to power two monitors.

Computer monitor has a VGA outlet and DVI outlet. Not sure which is better?

Can two VGA-USB cables from both monitors connect into a multi port USB adaptor type-C cable. Then plug the newly converted type-C cable into your Apple type-C Thunderbolt dock?

There’s a $10 multi port USB type-C adapter at office Max. The multi port USB converter has four USB spots to plug into (I would only need to use two of them) which then is converted into one type-C cable which I can then plug into computer?

Comment: Is this an answer or another question..? There seem to be a lot of queries within your post.